# Can't flag close on a bountied question

Tags: bug

This question: [Convince my supervisor for me to switch my research field to his major area halfway in my PhD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/convince-my-supervisor-for-me-to-switch-my-research-field-to-his-major-area-half)

seems off-topic for me as it depends on the personal circumstances and relationship between the student and advisor. As ff says, "talk to him."

Of course, whether to close should be a community decision, but I can't even flag to close because there's a bounty. This seems like a bug in the SE model as one could "protect" one's own posting from getting flagged for closure by putting a bounty on it.

Thoughts?

Comment: There's an existing feature request on main SE meta, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions). Go ahead and vote for it :)